# if $G$ and $H$ be groups with $\mathbb{Z}G \simeq \mathbb{Z}H$ then $\frac{G}{G^{'}}\simeq \frac{H}{H^{'}}$.

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

If $G$ and $H$ be groups with $\mathbb{Z}G \simeq  \mathbb{Z}H$ then $\frac{G}{G^{'}}\simeq \frac{H}{H^{'}}$.

It will be great if you help me with this. Any hint or guidance will be great. Thanks.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275249/quotient-of-ideal-in-group-ring-is-isomorphic-to-abelianization.

Comment: @Eric, $G'$ is standard notation for the derived subgroup, aka $[G,G]$. The quotient $G/G'$ is called the abelianization, sometimes denoted $G^{\rm ab}$ (cuz every abelian image of $G$ is a quotient of $G^{\rm ab}$).

Comment: I figured it was something standard but I can't just go around searching "G'" online :D

Comment: @EricStucky, my fault.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:  Is it clear *a priori* that an isomorphism of the group algebras would have to be compatible with the augmentation ideals (which I think would be needed to apply the approach your comment suggests)?